# How to map database column to EF model property in a more efficient way than I'm doing now

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a nullable `varchar(max)` column in SQL Server that I'm mapping to a `Guid?` in EF code-first. However, this property is actually in a base class that many other entities derive from.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model1>().Property(e => e.Property1).HasConversion(p => p.ToString(), p => (Guid?)Guid.Parse(p));
}
```

The above line is repeated many times for each table. Is there a way to tell EF that this is a base class property so the mapping can be declared only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible. With the lack of custom conventions, it is achieved with the "typical" `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` loop. Something like this (just change the base class and the property names):

```
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)));

var valueConverter = new ValueConverter<Guid, string>(
    v => v.ToString(), v => (Guid?)Guid.Parse(v));

foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    entityType.FindProperty(nameof(BaseClass.Property1)).SetValueConverter(valueConverter);
```

You may also consider using the EF Core provided out of the box `Guid` to `String` converter:

```
var valueConverter = new GuidToStringConverter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to make next calculation property:

```
[Column("Property1")]
public string Property1Raw { get; set; }

[IgnoreDataMember]
public Guid? Property1
{
    get => Guid.TryParse(Property1AsString, out Guid result) ? result : (Guid?)null;
    set => Property1Raw = value?.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is it to have a matching base class `IEntityTypeConfiguration`:

```
internal class EntityConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : Entity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.Property1).HasConversion(p => p.ToString(), p => (Guid?)Guid.Parse(p));
        // ... Other base-specific config here
    }
}
```

(Assuming here your base class is called `Entity` - change as needed).

This works better when you use the pattern of factoring out your entity configurations, so yours might be like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Model1EntityConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Model2EntityConfiguration());
    // ...
}
```

...

```
internal sealed class Model1EntityConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Model1>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Model1> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder); // <-- here's the key bit
        // ...; e.g.
        builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(80).IsRequired();
    }
}
```